# PHPUnit always takes me to login page,. regardless of what I do

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

So I am having a bit of an interesting problem. I am trying to build a forum for my website. I am trying to create a test that ensures registered users can submit new forum threads. Now, regardless of what I do, the test always ends up at the login paghe, even though I am logged in.

Here is something interesting, however, when I attempt to `dd()` the thread immediately after creation, Laravel seems to "skip over" the `dd` command and I end up with the "Thread title not found on the login page" error. I can `dd()` the `$request` object and that prints out fine, however, it seems after creating a new Thread model does Laravel skip over the `dd($thread)` command and I end up getting the login page once again.

I am pulling my hair out. Why is this happening?

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Thread;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class CreateThreadsTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseMigrations;

    function test_an_authenticated_user_can_create_new_forum_threads() {
            $this->be(factory('App\User')->create());

            $thread = factory('App\Thread')->make();

            $this->post('forum/threads', $thread->toArray());

            // you are missing this line
            $this->get($thread->path())->assertSee($thread->title)->assertSee($thread->body);


        }



}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Thread;
class ThreadsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $threads = Thread::latest()->get();
        return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $thread = Thread::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->id,
            'title' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body
        ]);



       return redirect($thread->path());
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Thread $thread)
    {
        return view('threads.show', compact('thread'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thread extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function path() {
        return "/forum/threads/" . $this->id;
    }

    public function replies() {
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
    }

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function addReply($reply) {
        $this->replies()->create($reply);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're making a new request unauthenticated, I already answered this question just moments ago ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I would say check your `routes` to see if you are accessing a route that has `Auth` middleware on it - if so, laravel will send you to login page. There's many ways to exclude a route from `Auth` middleware, one being editing your `Kernel.php`

Comment: I am authenticated, and I haven't set up sny middleware yet, so those aren't the issue. Check my test code, You'll see I did ``$this->be($user)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `make` a new model using the `factory` helper, it doesn't have an ID

for example

[image]

So `$thread->path()` will return just `"/forum/threads/"` which is not what you want

You have to make the request to the location from the response or query the newly created Thread record

```php
public function test_users_can_create_statuses()
{
  $this->be(factory('App\User')->create());
  $thread = factory('App\Thread')->make();
  $response = $this->post('/forum/threads', $thread->toArray());
  $this->get($response->headers->get('Location'))
             ->assertSee($thread->title);
             ->assertSee($thread->body);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I am testing to see if the store method handles the post request (IE create the model with dummy values, post it to the store method and then create the model on the controller). I am not persisting the model to the database because that would defeat the purpose of the whole test :\

Comment: If you don't persist a model to the database, how do you expect to "see" it on a route path view (threads.show)? You know that the Route Model Binding is actually doing a query right?

Comment: You'll understand after watching this: https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/6

Comment: I watched, followed and practiced all 102 episodes 2 years ago :)

Comment: Okay, what I don't understand is this: why would I even write a test in the first place if that model is persisted to the database before the post request? AM I not just creating the dummy data with ``make``, then attempt to persist the model via the ``store`` I'm not trying to be rude or anything, I'm just a bit confused

Comment: The make method returns an array from the factory (without ID or created_at and updated_at attributes), it's not persisted yet, then that data is posted to the controller store method which will persist the model and return a response, when you make a request to `$thread->path()` it's coming from the variable in `factory make` which has no ID so the route is completely incorrect

Comment: You can `dd($thread->path())` in your test after the post request and I'll bet you it'll be `"/forum/threads/"` :)

Comment: You're welcome, keep in mind that Jeffrey Way sometimes fixes the issues on the next video... happy coding